# Debian Package Creation postinst as non-root

Tags: linux, deb

I have created quite a few deb files, i have no problems doing that and they all run beautifully. However, if i want to replace a file in users home directory I am unsure on how to do that.

I have tried making a postinst to rsync the files from a predefined location to home directory, but since the postinst file is being run as root ( due to the debian installer running as root ) it is being sent to the root home directory and not the user's home directory....

Here's an example of the deb file contents :

> Debian Directory ---> Control File ----> Postint File
>
> usr/share/desktop (directory with files inside)

The postinst file has the sync command to send those files to users home:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -av /usr/share/desktop/ ~/.config/desktop/
```

The problem is it is sending the files to Root/home... not the default users home :(

I don't have the username of the user since this will be used on many computers with different users, therefore I can't use `sudo -u username`.

So what do I do? how do i replace files in users home directory from deb install? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In a Bash script, `~` refers to the *current* user's home directory. The package installation scripts are always run as root, so that's what "current user" means in this context.

(You could argue that the package installation is probably initiated by a user running `su` or `sudo`, but in the general case, you cannot assume this to be the case.)

Modifying user files from a system package appears extremely suspicious in any event. If the need is genuine, this should probably not be approached as a system package installation question in the first place. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Not only are you violating the basic principle that package management should not meddle with user files; a consequence of this arrangement is that the operation can only be performed once: If the user has installed the package, attempting to install it again does nothing (at least until you uninstall).

A more manageable and predictable approach would seem to be making the package provide this functionality, but leave it to the user to invoke the actual sync (overwriting) script as needed.  Perhaps you want to hook it into the desktop startup scripts somehow.

Having said that, `sudo` exposes the invoking user's identity in `$SUDO_USER` so you could look for that, and simply fail if it is not set.

As an aside, package scripts should work with `dash` so you need to avoid bashisms - prefer `$HOME` over `~`, for example.

Comment: I am trying to make a backup of the Xfce panel, theme, icons, wallpaper and Desktop Settings files within .config folder, and various other settings as well. Putting it into deb files, so someone else can simply run the deb files and have all the settings "restored" as they were on original system.  

I know there are other ways to do it, but i have to supply these settings via repository, so deb files is a must.... I need to find a way to restore these files back to the user home folder whatever the username may be and overwrite existing files.

Comment: I already have most of the stuff done in deb format, it all works really well. It is just the home directory specific files that are the problem, i need to find a way to restore these files when user install the selected deb file. Ofcourse i included a warning that files will be over written, but if he clicks yes it must still do the proper action, which it is not.

Comment: Updated the answer somewhat.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround, although it is not exactly what I was looking for, but here is my solution, at least for now.

```
#!/bin/sh
#This will move the desktop settings to required folder.

szAnswer=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter your login username\nThis must be entered correctly\n" --entry-text "Enter name of profile to use:")
xfce4-terminal -e "sudo rsync -av /usr/share/Desktop/ /home/$szAnswer/.config/xfce4/" 

exit 0
```

In other words, the user gets asked to enter his username, and the files get copied to that user's home directory. The advantage is that if he does have multiple users, it will use the correct user. The disadvantage is if he enters username wrong, even a spelling mistake, the install will fail.

But it does work, I have tested. If anyone has a better solution I eagerly await your suggestions.

Comment: This requires the user to have a working XFCE session, which seems to somewhat counter the purpose of the script. Also, it obviously allows a malicious user to overwrite another user's configuration files.

Comment: A less intrusive approach would be for the dialog to simply set a configuration file in `/etc`, and leave it to the system-wide XFCE scripts to zap the user's files the next time s/he logs in, and then remove the flag file.

Comment: As a very late afterthought, `sudo rsync` will create files owned by somebody else than the directory owner, meaning they basically cannot be manipulated by the user whose directory you are writing to. This is another violation of basic package hygiene, though I guess it will be easy to fix (`sudo` to the given user, or fix up the copied files with `chown`, or maybe there's an option to `rsync` to transfer ownership).